# How can I add the UIImageView of objects in an array to a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have two Objects, one is called CollidableController and the other is Collidable. Collidable controller creates Collidables and adds them to an array (which in this case is acting like a queue) but I'm struggling to add the UIImageView of the Collidable to the current View. It works fine before I add it to the array but I can't add the one that's in the array

```
 Collidable  *collidable = [[Collidable alloc] init:0];

[leftMovingBytesQueue enqueue:collidable];
//used a category to add this to NSMutableArray so it can act as a queue, this adds the 'collidable' object to the end of the array

[view addSubview:collidable.spriteImage];
collidable.spriteImage.center=CGPointMake(200, 200);
//adding the original collidable object's uiimageview to a view works fine

int length=[leftMovingBytesQueue count]-1;

[view addSubView:[leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:length].spriteImage];
 //this line doesn't work, I get the error Semantic Issue: Property 'spriteImage' not found on object of type 'id'
```

Comment: This is a good reason not to create compound statements.  In any case, when errors like this appear a good way to debug is to split the compound statement into it's component statements.  In this case there are three component statements.  When the separate statements work then recombine if that is one's style.

Comment: I need to add the object's UIImageView in the array though, creating another object from the one in the array and then adding that's UIImageView won't do what I want. Is that possible  (maybe using pointers? I've fairly new to them so I'm not sure)

Comment: @user660582: This does not address your problem, but `NSMutableArray` has a method `lastObject`, which you may find useful.

Comment: THe problem appears to be with the line `[leftMovingBytesQueue enqueue:collidable];`. Try logging the type of the `lastObject` after this, and you may find the bug.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"object type is: %@", [[leftMovingBytesQueue lastObject] class]);`

Comment: "object type is: (null)"
That sounds like the problem.

Comment: This is the code that adds the object
     - (void) enqueue:(id)anObject {
     [self addObject:anObject];
    }

Comment: I tried adding the object using addObject, rather than my own method and it still gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "addSubview" not "addSubView". Mind the lowercase 'v'.
Try This:

```
Collidable  *collidableObj=(Collidable*)[leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView* imView=collidableObj.spriteImage; //just checking
[view addSubview:imView];
```

You are enqueing the collidable object. try with [leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:0]. The last element of the array might not be what you want.

Comment: the second line gives me this:
 warning: Semantic Issue: Instance method '-addSubView:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
And then the program quits when it gets there.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Try running and see if your collidable object correctly retaining the UIImageView.

Comment: Same result.
Judging by the comments on the question I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Ah!! I see the error. Use "addSubview" not "addSubView". Mind the lowercase 'v'

Comment: That fixed the error but it gives the same result as jmosesman's answer below. When I try to get the type of the object in the array I get null.

Comment: You are enqueing the collidable object. try with [leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:0]. The last element of the array might not be what you want.

Comment: I tried that and it's the same result.
I'm guessing I've done something really stupid with the array.
Edit: NSLoged the array, it's completely empty.

Comment: Then you haven't alloc, init the array.Use [NSMutableArray alloc] init]

Comment: Now that's embarrassing.
That worked, I had it as a class property and didn't realise I had to do that.
Thank you so much, you've solved both of my problems :D

Answer (score 1):

```
[view addSubView:[[leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:length] spriteImage]];
```

This should make compiler happy.

Comment: That got rid of the error message but when I tried to run it I got "Program received signal: "SIGABRT"" when it got to that line and I get the warning "Semantic Issue: Instance method '-addSubView:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the object into your custom class:

```
[view addSubView:(Collidable*)[leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:length].spriteImage];
```

Comment: I tried that but I get the same error as before:
 error: Semantic Issue: Property 'spriteImage' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: And have you set a property on the `UIImageView` like `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *spriteImage` and synthesized it?

Comment: Yep, I have. It works when doing it without the array, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @jmosesman, @user660582. Shouldn't it be [view addSubView: ((Collidable *)[leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:length]).spriteImage];?

Comment: I'm not sure with the dot syntax.  If you did (Collidable*)[leftMovingBytesQueue objectAtIndex:length] spriteImage]; that should work.  But you could try adding some extra parentheses.

Comment: Ah, progress. That didn't give me any errors or warnings and ran smoothly it just didn't seem to do anything. The UIImageView didn't appear in the view.